# Using Jetpack Compose Paging library without Flow

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'd like to use Compose Paging library without Kotlin Flow but I' ve found only one example with Flow, where I have to collect data with collectAsLazyPagingItems() extension function. How to achieve identical behavior without flow ?

Comment: Typical XY problem. You want to do something. Figure out how to do it. Don't figure out how to achieve your made up solution (the one where you don't use flow)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. Whole paging is based on flow, this is just the official api. Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use flow?